# Program wont progress after firebase user registration

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

This activity registers a user in firebase auth, uploads info in Realtime database and uploads user picture in Storage.
This code (I don't know why) gets stuck when it registers the user. If you see, I've added Log statements to break this entire process. The log is like

```
STARTING PROCESS
BEFORE 
INSIDE
```

No other statement. I think I am using coroutines correctly but I don't know why this program doesn't go further than this ^. Should I use callbacks? Am I using coroutines in a wrong way?A lso any other suggestion will be appreciated.

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage
    private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
    val TAG ="SIGNUPATAG"
    var selectedPhoto : Uri? = null
    var IMAGE_RESPONE_CODE = 1;
    var isOk = false;
    val imageUrl : String = "."
    var userUID = "."
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        binding.signupTvSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent();
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Pic"),IMAGE_RESPONE_CODE)
        }
        binding.signupBtnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            val email = binding.signupEtvEmail.text.toString()
            if(email.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                binding.signupEtvEmail.error = "Invalid Email Address"
                binding.signupEtvEmail.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            if(binding.signupEtvName.text.length < 3) {
                binding.signupEtvName.error= "Name should at least have 3 characters"
                binding.signupEtvName.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            val password = binding.signupEtvPassword.text.toString()
            if(password.length < 4) {
                binding.signupEtvPassword.error = "Password should at least have 4 characters."
                binding.signupEtvPassword.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            // All Okay
            Log.d(TAG,"STARTING PROCESS")
            binding.pbSignup.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            createAccount(email,password,binding.signupEtvName.text.toString())
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if(data != null) {
                selectedPhoto = data?.data
                binding.signupImgvPhoto.setImageURI(selectedPhoto)
            }
            else {
                val context = this
                selectedPhoto = Uri.parse(
                    ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"
                        + context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.profilepicnormall) + '/'
                        + context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.profilepicnormall) + '/'
                        + context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.profilepicnormall) )
            }

        }
    }

    private fun createAccount(email : String, password : String,name:String) {
        val context = this
        selectedPhoto = Uri.parse(
            ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"
                    + context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.profilepicnormall) + '/'
                    + context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.profilepicnormall) + '/'
                    + context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.profilepicnormall) )
        lifecycleScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {

            async {
                create(email,password)
            }.await()
            Log.d(TAG,"The isOk is $isOk")
            if(isOk){
                async {
                    Log.d(TAG,"in 1 async")
                    uploadImage()
                }.await()
                async {
                    Log.d(TAG,"in 2 async")
                    uploadDataToRealtimeDatabase(userUID,email,name,imageUrl)
                }.await()
                binding.pbSignup.visibility = View.GONE
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
            binding.pbSignup.visibility = View.GONE

        }
    }

    suspend fun create(email: String,password: String) {
        Log.d(TAG,"BEFORE")
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(parent) {task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity,"SignUp Successful.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                isOk = true;
                userUID = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
                Log.d(TAG,"INSIDE")
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG,"${task.exception} . ")
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity,"SignUp Not Successful.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"AFTER")
    }

    suspend fun uploadDataToRealtimeDatabase(UID:String,userEmail: String,userName : String,url:String) {
        Log.d(TAG,"in upload data")
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://firechat-931d2-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/")
            .getReference("/users/$UID")
        val userinfo = UserInfo(userEmail,UID,userName,url)
        ref.setValue(userinfo).addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d(TAG,"UPLOADED USER INFORMATION")
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Log.d(TAG,"${it.message} $it")
        }
    }

    suspend fun uploadImage() : String  {
        Log.d(TAG,"in upload Image")
        val profilePicName = "${firebaseAuth.uid}.profileImage"
        var url = "."
        val storage_reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://firechat-931d2.appspot.com").getReference("/ProfileImages/$profilePicName")
        storage_reference.putFile(selectedPhoto!!).continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG,"${task.exception}")
            }
            storage_reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                url = it.toString()
            }.addOnFailureListener{
                Log.d(TAG,"$it ${it.message}")
            }
        }

        if(url.length < 2) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Going with default url.")
            url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firechat-931d2.appspot.com/o/ProfileImages%2FsqE6s03wgXQm7gl03xxQIM3JVQc2.profileImage?alt=media&token=640266a5-6611-4e09-b8ed-72ba8bdfdc1f"

        }
        Log.d(TAG,"returning the img url $url")
        return url
    }

}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is explained in this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8). It contains a video and Github repo.

Comment: @AlexMamo this uses Kotlin Flow which currently is a bit advanced for me. How can I solve this issue of my program not going forward beyond the register user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented only the signup part in a dummy app after fixing some issues with your code, here are my observations:

> No other statement

My logs were as follows:

```
D/SIGNUPATAG: STARTING PROCESS
D/SIGNUPATAG: INSIDE
D/SIGNUPATAG: The isOk is true
D/SIGNUPATAG: in 1 async
D/SIGNUPATAG: in upload Image
D/SIGNUPATAG: in 2 async
D/SIGNUPATAG: in upload data
```

> I think I am using coroutines correctly but I don't know why this program doesn't go further than this ^. Should I use callbacks? Am I using coroutines in a wrong way?

I don't think you're using coroutines as intended, `Firebase` calls are already asynchronous so you don't require to do it this way, you should use Firebase coroutines instead which have built-in support for this case. I am adding the changes that I made below. (Omitting the stuff that doesn't require any change)

> **build.gradle**

```
//firebase coroutines dependency
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.2"
```

> **SignUpActivity.kt**

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
.
.

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
.
.
}

private fun createAccount(email : String, password : String,name:String) {
     lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

        val createdUserJob = launch {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity,"SignUp Successful.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                isOk = true;
                userUID = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
                Log.d(TAG,"INSIDE")
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity,"SignUp Not Successful.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        createdUserJob.join()

        Log.d(TAG,"The isOk is $isOk")
        if(isOk){
            val uploadImageJob = launch {
                Log.d(TAG,"in 1 async")
                uploadImage()
            }
            uploadImageJob.join()

            val uploadDataJob = launch {
                Log.d(TAG,"in 2 async")
                uploadDataToRealtimeDatabase(userUID,email,name,imageUrl)
            }
            uploadDataJob.join()

            binding.pbSignup.visibility = View.GONE
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        binding.pbSignup.visibility = View.GONE

    }
}

    suspend fun uploadDataToRealtimeDatabase(UID:String,userEmail: String,userName : String,url:String) {
       Log.d(TAG,"in upload data")
       .
       .
     }

suspend fun uploadImage() : String  {
    Log.d(TAG,"in upload Image")
    .
    .
    return "dummy"
}
}
```

**Note:** I have only tested the signup part, you need to test the image upload and upload data part on your own, I've removed the `create(email: String,password: String)` method as well.

Comment: That dependency worked. @mehulbisht Thank you.